# does anyone know anything about this error? I can't solve

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, angular-dart, dart-pub

E/flutter (17200): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'findRootAncestorStateOfType' was called on null.

Comment: You need to post the minimal complete code that causes this error...

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused when you are using context before your Widget is build.

Try this code:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  // put the code here where you are using context.
});
```

I hope this helps, in case of any doubt please comment. *If this answer helps you then please accept and up-vote it.*

Answer (score -1):

I got this error when executing some code after calling `Navigator.of(context).pop()`. Your `BuildContext` object is null.

Comment: please post a question

Comment: @iamyadunandan It's an alternate answer, not a question. If you try to use the context after popping it then this error will occur. Please don't downvote when you don't understand.